# django don't redirect my after login

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

i use django auth module, it style blocked in 192.168.10.100:8080/verif_login and don't redirect me anyway,

this is my login.html page:

```
<form action="{% url 'authenticat:verif_login' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
           <th>Login</th>
           <td><input type="text"  class="login-inp" name="username" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th>Mot de passe</th>
           <td><input type="password"  name="password"  class="login-inp" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th></th>
           <td><input type="submit" class="submit-login"  /></td>
       </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

this is my views :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here. 

@csrf_exempt
def log_page(request):
  return render(request, 'authenticat/login.html', {})

@login_required
def val(request):
 return render(request, 'authenticate/val.html', {})


def verif_login(request):
  username = request.POST['username']
  password = request.POST['password']
  user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
  if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
      login(request, user)
      return redirect('authenticat:val')
    else:
      return redirect('authenticat:log_page')
  else:
    return redirect('authenticat:log_page')
```

this is my authenticat/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'$', views.log_page, name='log_page'),
   url(r'verif_login$', views.verif_login, name='verif_login'),
   url(r'val$', views.val , name='val'),
]
```

this is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   # Examples:
   # url(r'^$', 'proj.views.home', name='home'),
   # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  
   url(r'^', include('authenticat.urls', namespace='authenticat')),
]
```

Comment: Does it hit your view or doesn't anything happen when you click Submit?

Comment: yes when i click submit, it hit the verif_login and then it stop

Comment: i use django 1.8 and python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, redirect_url))
    # ...
```

Not the most beautiful solution, but it should work.

Also I'm not sure if your if statement `user.is_active` is necessary because this check is also happening in the `login()` method. (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active))

So to be sure, check if your if statements are working correctly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your url pattern for `log_page` is missing a `^`, which means it currently matches all urls, including `verif_login`. It should be:

```
url(r'^$', views.log_page, name='log_page'),
```

Note that Django comes with several [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), including a login view. I recommend that you use this, rather than write your own.